# How can I provide callbacks for an AngularStrap or Angular UI Bootstrap Popover, to execute on open and on close?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

I am using the Angular UI Bootstrap popover ( http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover ) and would like to specify a callback function to execute when it is opened and another for when it is closed.  My use case is that I am using the popover to contain filters for a grid of data.  I would like to load some remote filtering options on open, apply the selected filters only when the popover is closed.

The documentation only appears to support a few basic options but no indication of callback support.  I'm not seeing anything in the source code either.  Is my only option to set an interval function to check periodically if the popover is visible in the DOM?

I'm also considering Angular Strap's popover to achieve the same result, but can't seem to find the option to set callbacks there either.

Answer (score 5):

Seems that Koni's and user2453461's answers no longer work as `popover.js` utilizes [tooltip.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js) that does the emit event. You should be able to do the following:

```
$scope.$on('tooltip.show.before', function() {
    console.log("show before");
 });

$scope.$on('tooltip.show', function() {
    console.log("show");
 });


$scope.$on('tooltip.hide.before', function() {
  console.log("hide before");
});

$scope.$on('tooltip.hide', function() {
  console.log("hide");
});
```

Not sure how good an idea this is, though, as the syntax seems to change over versions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for AngularStrap.  It emits `popover-*` events that I can hook into here:

> https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/3c8bd1d37ab3b023bd79f9b0c1a6931b18e2ac84/src/directives/popover.js#L110

So using this in my popover controller I can hook into hidden/shown.  This is for modals but works the same for the popover with the `popover-` prefix

> https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/107#issuecomment-16701662

Comment: This does not work anymore. The popover.js does not `$emit` anything, it seems: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/popover/popover.js.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked as user2453461 said:

```
$scope.$on('popover-shown', function() {
    console.log("SHOWN");
 });

 $scope.$on('popover-hidden', function() {
    console.log("HIDDEN");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Popover "inherits from" `$tooltip`, which `$emit`s a `tooltip.hide.before` and then a `tooltip.hide` event. However, since it is `$emit`ing and not `$broadcast`ing, only the popover's scope (and its children, but it is unlikely to have any) has access to the event.

In my code (coffeescript), this looks like:

```
.directive 'ngPopoverParent', ($popover) ->

  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->

    popover = $popover element,
      'title': attrs.title
      'content': attrs.content
      'animation': attrs.animation
      'trigger': 'click'

    popover.$promise.then ->
      popover.$scope.$on 'tooltip.hide', ->
        console.log('tooltip hidden!')
```

Relevant source: 
https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/08167f7d5f52424b0f6fe40f3a053e134f550472/src/tooltip/tooltip.js